# Regex - Validate Alpharumeric with dot (mandatory)

Tags: javascript, regex

Need your help in modifying the below regex I have.

**Requirement**
Should match the given string with Alpharumeric and a **dot(.)**. Note that **dot (.)** is mandatory and it should not comes in the first or at last. Numeric is **not** mandatory.

**Valid Inputs**

1. abc.xyz
2. abc123.xyz123
3. a.1

**Invalid Values**

1. .abc.xyz
2. 123.123
3. abcd
4. a1.s.d.3.4
5. asd123.
6. a2....b2

***Note: First character should be a alphabet and only single dot should appear.***

*My regex (not working for all the scenario)*

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\.]*$/
```

Thanks for any inputs.

*Thanks to all the users who have provided the answers. Unfortunately I have to make only one as 'Accepted'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
/^^[a-z](?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)[a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9]$/gmi
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eY5hM5/3)

Comment: `asd...asd` is not a valid input that I wanted.

Comment: By what rule it is invalid? Do you want to block more than 1 dot?

Comment: Check edited answer now. It won't match `asd...asd` now.

Comment: Yes I have already taken care of that. You can see updated answer and new demo link.

Comment: It is strange you have accepted an answer that is breaking your own rule and matching input like `a.1.2.3`

Comment: oops. didn't checked that one out.

Answer (score 1):

If the dot mustn't come last (and if (as I suspect) `a...b` wouldn't be valid either), you can use

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)+$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Start of string
[a-z]       # Match one ASCII letter
[a-z0-9]*   # Match zero or more ASCII letters/digits
(?:         # Start a group:
 \.         # that starts with a dot
 [a-z0-9]+  # and continues with one or more ASCII letters/digits
)+          # Match that group one or more times
$           # until the end of the string
```

This works for one or more dots. If only one dot is allowed, the regex is trivial:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*\.[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Comment: The regex is not working for `abc123.asd`. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @Java_User: It works for that string...not sure where your problem is.

Comment: Please check the previous answers, comments and my updated question.

Comment: @Java_User: From your initial question it appeared that multiple dots were allowed. If they aren't, the regex is trivial. No need for lookaround assertions or other complex stuff.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll take a look at it. And I'm sorry if my initial question was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:[0-9]+)?)\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/9)

This allows only one  dot character.

Comment: It should not match that. Please check @anubhava's answers comments.

Comment: why you don't want to match `a1.s.d.3.4` and want to match `a.1`?

Comment: Edited my question. I need to have only one instance of dot.

Comment: just put the dot outside the second non-capturing group. See http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/9

Comment: Thanks. Actually I don't wanted to vote up for the incorrect answer.